# can any one give me some sample code on how to generate a mail if value exceeds thrsold

Tags: jms, jmx

hi i am monitoring jvm and i am getting it statics like memory,number of threads etc
and i want to generate mail notification depending on that conditions. can any give me some sample code on how to generate mails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaMail download contains examples for how to use the javax.mail API:

http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/FAQ.html#examples

Look at the demo folder in the javamail-1.4.2.zip

Another approach would be to use log4j or another logging framework that supports an "Smtp/Email" appender.  See the log4j site for examples on how to setup email logging.